# using "next" statement with variable result in StopIteration

Tags: python, dictionary, iterator

Can anybody explain why:

```
table ={1249.99: 36.30, 
        1749.99: 54.50, 
        2249.99: 72.70, 
        2749.99: 90.80, 
        3249.99: 109.00, 
        3749.99: 127.20,
        4249.99: 145.30}

x = 1000
y = next(x for x in table if x > 1000) work fines
```

on the hand other doing it below gives a StopIteration

```
y = next(x for x in table if x > x)
```

Comment: Can't replicate both `raise StopIteration`

Comment: Should your `table` have something in it to demonstrate the problem?

Comment: `x > x` is never true, thus the iterator is *always* empty

Comment: both cases gave me `StopIteration` in **Python 2.7** and **Python 3.6**

Comment: my apologies, updated the question, to make it more clear.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The first one works because `x` will always be greater than 1000, since **the `x` variable isn't the same `x` you defined on the previous line**, but instead, the `x` from `for x in table`. So `x` are the next key from `table`. And that all the keys are greater than 1000, so the iterator created isn't empty.

```
next(x for x in table if x > 1000)
# similar to:
# next(iter((1249.99, 1749.99, 249.99, 2749.99, 3249.99, 3749.99, 4249.99)))
```

The second example raised `StopIteration` because `x` will never be greater than `x`, which means you're getting the next iteration from a empty iterator.

```
next(x for x in table if x > x)
# similar to:
# next(iter(()))
```

Consider the following:

Your code is equivalent to this:

```
def gen_a(table):
    for x in table: # same as for x in table.keys()
        if x > 1000:
            yield x

def gen_b(table):
    for x in table:  # same as for x in table.keys()
        if x > x: # will never happen
            yield x

table ={1249.99: 36.30, 
        1749.99: 54.50, 
        2249.99: 72.70, 
        2749.99: 90.80, 
        3249.99: 109.00, 
        3749.99: 127.20,
        4249.99: 145.30}

x = 1000 # note that x isn't in the same scope as the other x's

print(next(gen_a(table))) # result varies since dict are unordered, I got 4249.99

print(next(gen_b(table))) # raises a StopIteration
```

Comment: thanks, that was a very detailed and easy to understand reply. very educational.